# What is the best way to pass flask variables directly to vue?

Tags: javascript, python, variables, flask, vue.js

I'm working on a vizualisation app with a flask server and vue.js for the front end.

Similar questions on the subject look for a way to make vue.js and flask variable syntax not enter in conflict like shown [here](https://github.com/yymm/flask-vuejs).

In my case, I'm wondering if there is anyway to directly assign vue.js variable data.d with a variable send from Flask render_template method.

```
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        'd': {{Flask-variable}}
      },
})
```

Here is the code

Flask

```
import os
import flask
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from script_python import kernel as K


def App():
    # Initialize the Flask application
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('marianaViz.config.ConfigClass')

    #return index.html on load
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        d = [{'x':1, 'y':0, 'z': 1},{'x':1, 'y':0, 'z': 2}]
        return flask.render_template("histogram.html",d= flask.jsonify(**K.JSONResponse(data = d,error=False,message='')))

    return app
```

js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'd':{{ d.data|tojson|safe}},
  },
  created:function(){
        this.drawHistogram(d),
      },
  methods:{
  // Called when the Visualization API is loaded.
    drawHistogram: function(){
      var data = null;
      var graph = null;
      var self = this;


      // Create and populate a data table.
      console.log(d);
        data = self.d;
        //data = [{x:1, y:0, z: 1},{x:1, y:0, z: 2},{x:2, y:0, z: 3},{x:3, y:0, z: 2},{x:4, y:0, z: 1},{x:5, y:0, z: 1},{x:6, y:0, z: 2},{x:7, y:0, z: 3},{x:8, y:0, z: 2},{x:9, y:0, z: 1},{x:10, y:0, z: 1},{x:11, y:0, z: 2},{x:12, y:0, z: 3},{x:13, y:0, z: 2},{x:14, y:0, z: 1},{x:15, y:0, z: 1},{x:16, y:0, z: 2},{x:17, y:0, z: 3},{x:18, y:0, z: 2},{x:19, y:0, z: 1}];

        // create some nice looking data with sin/cos

        /*
        function custom(x, y) {
        return (-Math.sin(x/Math.PI) * Math.cos(y/Math.PI) * 10 + 10);
        }
        var steps = 4;  // number of datapoints will be steps*steps
        var axisMax = 15;
        var axisStep = axisMax / steps;
        for (var x = 0; x <= axisMax; x+=axisStep) {
          for (var y = 0; y <= axisMax; y+=axisStep) {
            var z = custom(x,y);
              data.push({x:x, y:0, z: z});
          }
          console.log(data);
        }
        */

        // specify options
        var options = {
          width:  '300px',
          height: '300px',
          style: 'bar',
          xBarWidth: 0.5,
          yBarWidth: 0.5,
          showPerspective: true,
          showGrid: true,
          showShadow: false,
          "showYAxis":false,
          "xLabel":'',
          "zLabel":'',
          cameraPosition: {
              horizontal: 0*3.14,
              vertical: 0*3.14,
              distance: 1.8
            },
            legendLabel: '',
          keepAspectRatio: true,
          verticalRatio: 0.5,
          "backgroundColor":'black',
          "showLegend": true,
          "xCenter":'50%',
        };

        var camera = graph ? graph.getCameraPosition() : null;

        // create our graph
        var container = document.getElementById('histogram');
        graph = new vis.Graph3d(container, data, options);

        if (camera) graph.setCameraPosition(camera); // restore camera position


  }

    }
})
```

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--Vuejs-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for ('static',filename='js/vue.js')}}"></script>
    <!--css-->
    <link href="{{url_for ('static',filename='css/disp.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--Vis visualisation lib-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/front/lala_web/vis.js"></script>-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <h2>Histogram:</h2>
            <div id="histogram"></div>
        </div>
    </body >
        <!--display.js-->
         <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for ('static',filename='js/histogram.js')}}"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options and I'll show you 4 that will work for simple data types (int, strings etc) and with a little more effort, you can also make them work for more complex data types (arrays, objects etc)

1. Use inline JavaScript

Just assign the variable in a script tag

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
 #some var from flask
  var d_var = "{{somevalue}}" 
 </script>
```

Then in you vue script, you can do

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
  d: d_var
  ...
```

The remaining steps involve assigning the variable to the attribute of a DOM element (e.g a hidden input)

2. Use jQuery

Create a hidden input inside the main vue dom element with its value set to your flask variable

```
<input name="d_elem" type="hidden" value="{{somevalue}}" id="d_elem" />
```

Then in your vue script you can now do

```
var d_var = $("#d_elem").val(); 
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
  d: d_var
  ...
```

3. Use plain old getElementById

In case you suffer JS library fatigue, just create the hidden input like before but this time you do

```
 var d_var =  document.getElementById("d_elem").value;
 var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
  d: d_var
  ...
```

4. Use vm.$refs

Create the hidden input with ref attribute

```
<input name="d_elem" type="hidden" value="{{somevalue}}" ref="d_elem" />
```

Access it inside vue instance like

```
var d_var = this.$refs.d_elem.value ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like

```
'd':{{ flask_variable|tojson|safe }}
```

of coarse your variable would need to be json serializeable

you might have to actually parse the json back into js

`JSON.parse('{{ flask_variable|tojson|safe }}')` (at least something like that) and it has to be an object that can be converted to json (ie a python class probably wont work... strings and numbers should)

Comment: Hello Joran, thank you for your interest. I've tried your solution but I get a SyntaxError: invalid property id for {{ flask_variable|tojson|safe }}. I've edit my question to add the code in case the problem would be somewhere else.

Comment: I got some weird output on js side when using JSON.parse('{{ flask_variable|tojson|safe }}')  => "y\":="" 0,="" \"x\":="" 1,="" \"z\":="" 1},="" {\"y\":="" 2}]}"')="">